# ComboBox of CheckBoxes not checking item when row clicked

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, combobox

I've got a combo box of checkboxes that allow the user to select multiple temperature bands.  When the users clicks on the checkbox, or the text directly next to the checkbox, the boxes are checked correctly, and my combobox text updates to add/remove the selected temperature.  However if I check in the area of my combobox drop down to the right of the text, the checkbox isn't toggled, and instead I get namespace text in my combo box.
[image: ComboBox Text]

Here's my XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbDegrees" ItemsSource="{Binding m_DegreeValues}" Text="Degrees" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Background="Gray" >
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Name="chkDegrees" Content="{Binding Name}" Checked="Degrees_CheckBox_Click" Unchecked="Degrees_CheckBox_Click"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I would like to have the checkbox toggled when I click anywhere in the line item for the temperature.

Comment: ComboBox is not a general purpose DropDown Button of any sort.
It is a selector meant to provide you with means to select items from a collection.
If you wish to you can simply put together ToggleButton and a Popup  and bind them together.
Inside your Popup put a list of checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you @Mishka, I will consider your approach as a possible solution, but I already have all the other functionality that I desire in my combo box of check boxes.  I am just focused on fixing this one flaw, and others have done an excellent job of describing the issue I am having, and offering a solution on how to fix it.

Comment: I get it, its ok, Im just ocd about stuff and this bugs me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `ComboBoxItem` that is generated is not set to stretch and fill all available space. You can see this if you wrap your `ComboBox` in something like a `DockPanel` with it's Background property set.

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel Background="CornflowerBlue">
            <CheckBox Name="chkDegrees" Content="{Binding Name}" .. />
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

To fix it, set your `ComboBoxItem` style so it sets the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you Rachel.  I appreciate the example code so I could see the actual width of a checkbox item inside the dock panel.  Your solution works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an `ItemContainerStyle` that makes the `CheckBox` stretch horizontally:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbDegrees" ItemsSource="{Binding m_DegreeValues}" Text="Degrees" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Background="Gray" >
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="chkDegrees" Content="{Binding Name}" Checked="Degrees_CheckBox_Click" Unchecked="Degrees_CheckBox_Click"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```